# How can to adjust par() setting to fit a multi-panel plots?

Tags: r

The data for my code is
`payments <- read.csv("payments.csv", header = TRUE)`

The data file payments.csv was used which I uploaded here:
https://github.com/Bheal/Board-Q-A

I am learning R and wanted to accomplish the same this `ggplot(payments, aes( x = Average.Total.Payments, y = Average.Covered.Charges)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(DRG.Definition ~ Provider.State)` in base plotting, so I tried this:

```
par(mfrow = c(6,6))

for(state in unique(payments$Provider.City)) {
  for(condition in unique(payments$DRG.Definition)) {
    data.sub <- subset(payments, Provider.State == state & DRG.Definition == condition)
with(data.sub, plot(Average.Total.Payments ~ Average.Covered.Charges))
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I believe that first I have to to experiment on `par()` settings.  And maybe my intended 6x6 panel will show, but don't know where to start and while I search the web, wanted to post this here for relevant critique and advise.  Thanks.

Comment: I have read this and another post on stackoverflow but I can neither get the 6x6 graph that I want nor do I know what should I change my `par(mar=c(..)` to.  I tried something like c(1,1,1,1) and the error changed to `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values`... is there a source that one should turn to for explanation of all the par settings?